# sqoop import into hive

Tags: hive, sqoop

1st command:

```
sqoop import \
–connect “jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db” \
–username retail_dba \
–password cloudera \
–table departments \
–hive-home /user/hive/warehouse \
–hive-import \
–hive-overwrite \
–hive-table sqoop_import.departments \
–outdir java_files
```

2nd command:

```
sqoop import \
–connect “jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db” \
–username retail_dba \
–password cloudera \
–table departments \
–target-dir=/user/hive/warehouse/department_test \
–append
```

In both the commands we are creating table in Hive without specifying field and line delimiters and importing using sqoop, then why in second case we are getting Null and not in first case

Comment: First of all 2nd command is not hive import command, it will fetch data from MySQL to specified  HDFS  `--target-dir`. Second, Getting NULL what?

Comment: Null data when I access the table department_test in hive

Comment: you are creating table with `/user/hive/warehouse/department_test` location in 2nd case?

Answer (score 0):

Hive's default delimiter

- Field:  `CTRL+A`
- LINE :   `\n`

**Case 1 : HIVE IMPORT**

Import tables into Hive (Uses Hive’s default delimiters if none are set.)

Also, it creates table mentioned in `--hive-table` *(if not exists)* with hive's default delimiter.

**Case 2 : HDFS IMPORT**

In this case, data from RDBMS is stored as `,` field delimiter and `\n` line delimiter *(default)* which is not the default delimiters for hive. That's why you are getting NULL entries in your data.

You can solve it using two ways:

- Change your hive table's field delimiter
- use `--fields-terminated-by`in your IMPORT command.